# One segue identifier used between two UIViewControllers for multiple UITableView cell data transfer?

Tags: uitableview, xcode4

In this case, I am assigning values below to `stringToDisplay` and want to send them to `SegViewController`, which also retains `stringToDisplay`. Do I need to use `cell.textLabel.text` here with `isEqualToString: @"Fire House Gallery`? Would I use `indexPath` or `UITableViewCell` here?

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
  SegViewController *seg = segue.destinationViewController;
  seg.delegate = (id)self;

  if ("......" isEqualToString: @"Firehouse Gallery"])
  {
      seg.stringToDisplay = @"Firehouse Gallery";
  }
  else
  {
      seg.stringToDisplay = @"Frog Hollow Craft Center";
  }
}
```

Thank you,
Greg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer for what I was looking for. I now have ONE `segue` link between two UIViewcontrollers, with the `segue identifier` called @"seg". For a place named Radio Bean, I use the following when the "Radio Bean" cell is pressed:

```
if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString: @"Radio Bean"])
{
     self.stringToDisplay = @"Radio Bean";
     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"seg" sender:self];
}
```

Then, in `prepareForSegue` I DO NOT specify `segue identifier` but use the following:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   SegViewController *seg = segue.destinationViewController;
   seg.delegate = (id)self;

   if ([self.stringToDisplay isEqualToString: @"Radio Bean"])
   {
       seg.stringToDisplay = @"Radio Bean";
   }
}
```

This successfully passes "Radio Bean" to the next `UIViewcontroller`, and I can include multiple  place options with the use of only ONE segue link, so, no need for multiple links.

Answer (score 1):

**The short answer:**

You shouldn't derive data from your table view cells because they are your view.  You should be "deriving data" from your model.

**The longer answer:**

Determining how to configure your segue depends on how you are calling it:

If you are calling it in code (using `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender`) then pass your string as the "sender" in your method call.

If you have setup the segue in your storyboard, then you should use different segues for each possibility, and check the segue identifier to determine which string that you should pass.